# override pattern lock to display toast

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-toast

Is is possible that a toast will get displayed of my application overriding every kind of lock in the device that exist when user press the power button twice in unrooted device. I am just few months old to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to override the lock screen but there is a way to co-operate with it. Starting from Android 4.2, you can write a [lock screen widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen) to display custom information on the lock screen.

Comment: and if it is possible that my application gets open on the double click of power button ?? overriding these locks ???

Answer (score 0):

Update:

> Only Android versions lower than 5.0 support lock-screen widgets. For Android 5.0 and higher, only home_screen is valid.

Source: [API Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen)